# How do I solve this level 74 question in Think Different?

Tags: think-different

I have been stuck on level 72 for a while, how do I solve this level?

[image]

Comment: Is this level 74 or 72? You mention both...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 12. If you were to add all the 3 digit-number, you'll find the answer in that circle except 516.
2+6+3=11
2+6+8=16
3+5+9=17